# Query Solr with Constraint List

Tags: solr, constraints, negation

I would like to query Solr for documents based on an array field that only have values of an array I pass in to the query.

If my constraint list contains [ A, B, C ] then I want to get documents that have [ A, C ] and [ B, C ] for example. In other words, I  do not want ones that have [ A, B, D ] since D is not in the constraint list.

This would be a sort of constraint list query or negation query.

Is there a way to do this in Solr? My only other option is to process the results manually after the fact and I would like to avoid this.

Comment: So you want something like "no other tokens, but the ones in this list"?

Comment: Correct, I am trying to implement a system where users can only view records they have all permissions required for.

Comment: Did you check the [document level security](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrSecurity#SolrSecurity-DocumentLevelSecurity) entry in their wiki? [This blog entry](https://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/solr-security-with-manifoldcf) is more informative.

Comment: Alternatively [this article from Erik Hatcher](https://lucidworks.com/post/custom-security-filtering-solr-5/) looks interesting, but would involve custom code.

Comment: Thank you for all of the articles. Do you know if there is a way to do this at the query level without configuring security? Sadly, due to how we have our permissions structured I am unsure if it would be practical or not. The sites and article you have referenced have been very insightful. If you want to compile your comments into an answer I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible without own custom code or:

## Apache Manifold

As the description of the project quotes:

> Apache ManifoldCF is an effort to provide an **open source framework for** connecting source content repositories like Microsoft Sharepoint and EMC Documentum, to target repositories or indexes, such as **Apache Solr**, Open Search Server, or ElasticSearch. Apache ManifoldCF also **defines a security model** for target repositories that permits them **to enforce source-repository security policies**.

There is a whole top level project dedicated to that task. Of course this will come at a certain cost in terms of query performance. But should you be within a corporate environment there are usually requirements from the corporate security that you need to obey. Hence this is worth a look.

This [great article by Srinivasa Sarma of thedigitalgroup](https://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/solr-security-with-manifoldcf) describes who to set this up. Your scenario might vary, as your source system may be different.

## Custom PostFilter

An alternative is to implement [Solr's PostFilter interface](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_1_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/PostFilter.html). How this can be done is described in [Custom Security Filter ing in Solr 5.X](https://lucidworks.com/post/custom-security-filtering-solr-5) by Erik Hatcher. This should result in faster query performance, but as you have now a piece of custom code, you need to take care of it.

I have done this in the past to be able to perform chemical substructure searches. Hence I know that this API is likely to change with a major release. Most of the time these changes are not hard. But you should know that you will very likely adapt this piece of code every 6 months. So get your tests up and running :)